# DNS not resolving IP

Tags: domain-name-system, http

I want my web-service (185.156.179.139) to be available by app.dotaquiz.org. So I've registered domain name. I've also created an A-record (app-A-185.156.179.139).

GET-request to http://185.156.179.139/users/1 gives OK-200.

GET-request to http://app.dotaquiz.org/users/1 gives 404.

What i am missing?

Comment: For issues similar to this; your DNS server may cache subsequent name lookups for the same domain. Try a different server if you're sure you've set it up correctly.

Comment: 404 vs 200 is not a DNS issue

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen Well, it is if the DNS Server is still pointing to an old server, which does not have this path

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your DNS seems fine, `app.dotaquiz.org` pointing to `185.156.179.139`:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
app.dotaquiz.org.       86400   IN      A       185.156.179.139
```

We can see that there isn't a web page configured for that hostname on the Nginx giving error:

> 404 Not Found
>
> nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

You should configure the Nginx `server {}` section for [server name](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html) `app.dotaquiz.org`.

Also, problems with DNS configuration would have caused other kind of errors, like

- `ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED` if the record wasn't configured at all
- `ERR_TIMED_OUT` / `ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` in case of wrong IP without a web server
- strange web page or foreign `404` error in case of wrong IP with a web server.

The `200 OK` and `404 Not Found` are *HTTP Response Status Codes* ([RFC 7231, 6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6)); always related to the HTTP protocol i.e. web server, not domain name service.